# Commenting on instagram ad post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I only see GET and DELETE calls,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/post_moderation/v2.6

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/setup/v2.6

Is possible to post a comment on an instagram Ad post, and How?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this feature is not supported yet.